# morphia-1.2.9a : An unexpected error occured caused by exception InstantiationError: play.data.binding.BeanWrapper

Tags: mongodb, playframework

play framework + morphia

Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /accountcontroller/signup

```
Oops: InstantiationError
An unexpected error occured caused by exception InstantiationError: play.data.binding.BeanWrapper

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:264)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationError: play.data.binding.BeanWrapper
        at play.modules.morphia.Model.edit(Model.java:101)
        at play.modules.morphia.Model.create(Model.java:87)
        at play.modules.morphia.Model.create(Model.java:79)
        at play.modules.morphia.MorphiaPlugin.bind(MorphiaPlugin.java:727)
        at play.PlayPlugin.bind(PlayPlugin.java:70)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.bind(PluginCollection.java:579)
        at play.data.binding.Binder.bind(Binder.java:103)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethodArgs(ActionInvoker.java:651)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)`enter code here`
        ... 1 more`enter code here`
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain your question a bit?

Comment: it seems that when my code execute model.save() or model.create(), the exception alert as above..but I can run it in my local dev environment.

Comment: What is your play version? I suspect you are using morphia plugin with an incompatible play

Comment: play 1.2.5
deps:
    morphia 1.2.9 
    japid
    press

they are compatible in my mac os x dev environment.
I install java, mongodb, play! in ubuntu server, and some exception as titled occurs, it's ok in my dev env.